# Uninstalling IBObjects on delphi 2010

Tags: delphi, delphi-2010

I installed ibobjects in delphi 2010 to give the components a try, now I want to uninstall them, I run the uninstaller but when I complie my existing proyects I get the following error:

[DCC Fatal Error] accedoCFD_2011.dpr(15): F1026 File not found: 'IB_Access.dcu'

And when I try to run my proyects outside the delphi ide y get a message like
"Thanks for evaulating ibobjects, please register at www.ibobjects.com"

I have tried to remove the componets manually form the component install packages menu, but I still see some empty tabs from ibobjects and still get the register message and the compiler error. I have searched in http://ibobjects.com/ for the solution but I did not found anything.
Any clues? Thanks in advance

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There's an `IB_Access` reference in one of your units' uses clause. As for the empty tabs, you can right click on them and then delete.

Comment: Thank you very much, that did the trick.
If I use the delphi 7 alike tool pallete I can still see the empty component tab of ibobjects, if I use the new layout in the tool palette the ibobjects components are gone.

Comment: @Alejandro - I don't have D2010, but older versions had a 'Palette' tab in 'Environment Options' dialog, and the corresponding settings were kept in the 'Palette' key in the registry. You can check for a similiar key, f.i. in 'HKCU\Software\CodeGear\BDS\7.0\Palette', and if it's there delete your empty tab there.

Comment: Thanks a lot, I opened the reg key and deleted all references to IBO but the tabs still there, weird!

Comment: @Alejandro - According to the following link, in fact, there still is an options page for it; http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/RADStudio/en/Component_Toolbar I hope it works, otherwise you'd better start getting used to the empty tab. :)